# pandas dataframe generic column values

Tags: pandas

Is there a consistent way of getting pandas column values by DF['ColName'], including index column? If 'ColName' is an index column, you get KeyError.

It is very inconvenient that every time you need to determine whether a column being passed in is an index column or not, then handle it differently.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        A=[1, 2, 3],
        B=[4, 5, 6],
        C=['x', 'y', 'z'],
    ),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [
            ('cat', 'red'),
            ('dog', 'blue'),
            ('bird', 'yellow')
        ],
        names=['species', 'color']
    )
)

print(df)

                A  B  C
species color          
cat     red     1  4  x
dog     blue    2  5  y
bird    yellow  3  6  z
```

you can always refer to levels of the index in the same way you'd refer to columns if you `reset_index()` first.

Grab column `'A'`

```
df.reset_index()['A']

0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Grab `'color'` without `reset_index()`

```
df['color']

> KeyError
```

With `reset_index()`

```
0       red
1      blue
2    yellow
Name: color, dtype: object
```

---

This doesn't come without it's downside.  That index was potentially useful to have for column `'A'`

```
df['A']

species  color 
cat      red       1
dog      blue      2
bird     yellow    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Automatically aligned the `'index'` with the values of column `'A'` which was the whole point of it being the index.